# NSArray adding elements

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have to create a dynamic NSArray, that is, I don't know the size of the array or what elements the array is going to have. The elements need to be added to the array dynamically. I looked at the NSArray class reference. There is a method called arrayWithObjects, which should be used at the time of initializing the array itself. But I don't know how to achieve what I need to do.

I need to do some thing like the following:

```
NSArray *stringArray = [[NSArray init] alloc] ;  
for (int i = 0; i < data.size; i++){  
    stringArray.at(i) = getData(i);
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you create an `NSArray` you won't be able to add elements to it, since it's immutable. You should try using `NSMutableArray` instead.

Also, you inverted the order of `alloc` and `init`. `alloc` creates an instance and `init` initializes it.

The code would look something like this (assuming `getData` is a global function):

```
NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i< data.size; i++){
   [stringArray addObject:getData(i)];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to add object in array if you are working with immutable array. Which is thread safe.

You can use `arrayByAddingObject` method. Some times it's much better. Here is discussion about it: [NSMutableArray vs NSArray which is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207386/nsmutablearray-vs-nsarray-which-is-better)

Comment: `[array arrayByAddingObject:@"mažiukas"];` does not add the new element.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas but it creates (and returns) a new array which contains all elements from original array plus new one. Sometimes it might be very helpful (for example, if you prefer working with non-mutable data-structures, like NSArray).

Answer (score 4):

Convert your NSArray to NSMutableArray, and then you can add values dynamically:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableStringArray = [stringArray mutableCopy];
[mutableStringArray addObject:@"theNewElement"];
```