# addObject to NSArray in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

How to addObject to NSArray using this code? I got this error message when trying to do it.

```
NSArray *shoppingList = @[@"Eggs", @"Milk"];
NSString *flour = @"Flour";
[shoppingList addObject:flour];
shoppingList += @["Baking Powder"]
```

Error message

```
/Users/xxxxx/Documents/iOS/xxxxx/main.m:54:23: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'
```

Comment: Use NSMutableArray instead because is dynamic

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSArray adding elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778465/nsarray-adding-elements)

Comment: NSMutableArray  *imageArray;                                                                                                                                    
    imageArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [imageArray addObject:imagename];

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`addObject` works on `NSMutableArray`, not on `NSArray`, which is immutable.

If you have control over the array that you create, make `shoppingList` `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *shoppingList = [@[@"Eggs", @"Milk"] mutableCopy];
[shoppingList addObject:flour]; // Works with NSMutableArray
```

Otherwise, use less efficient

```
shoppingList = [shoppingList arrayByAddingObject:flour]; // Makes a copy
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't add objects into NSArray. Use NSMutableArray instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Your array cant be changed because is defined as [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html) which is inmutable (you can't add or remove elements) Convert it to a [`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/) using this

```
NSMutableArray *mutableShoppingList = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithArray:shoppingList];
```

Then you can do

```
[mutableShoppingList addObject:flour];
```

Comment: Um, `[NSMutableArray shoppingList]`? Looks like your code is missing something.

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` does not have `addObject:` method, for this you have to use 
`NSMutableArray`. `NSMutableArray` is used to create dynamic array.

```
NSArray *shoppingList = @[@"Eggs", @"Milk"];
NSString *flour = @"Flour";

NSMutableArray *mutableShoppingList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: shoppingList];
[mutableShoppingList addObject:flour];
```

Or

```
NSMutableArray *shoppingList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Eggs", @"Milk",nil];
NSString *flour = @"Flour";
[shoppingList addObject:flour];
```